# animated marker or path with leaflet in shiny r

Tags: shiny, leaflet

I am new in shiny r and leaflet. I am trying to plot the moving tracks of cars at the moment.

As there is a plugin for leaflet js named animatedMaker, are there any techniques also could achieve this? I am trying to use leafletproxy and invidatelater. Here is my code, that is not working at all. Thanks a lot for help:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  #read data from csv
  latlon <- read.csv("tx_r1c_car_1.csv",header = TRUE)

  i<-0
  #filter time when user using the time slider
  filteredData <- eventReactive(input$searchtime,{
    latlon[latlon$time >= input$time[1] & latlon$time <= input$time[2],] 
    i = input$time[1]
  })

  #plot out limited marker every time
  mark <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(100,session)
    i = i+0.1
    filteredData[filteredData$time > i && filteredData$time <(i+0.2)]
  })

  observe({
    invalidateLater(100,session)
    leafletProxy("hist", data = mark()) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      #addPolylines(~long,~lat,popup = ~as.character(speed))
      addMarkers(~long,~lat,popup = ~as.character(speed))  
  })

  #render leaflet
  output$hist <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      setView(lng = 150.8897244, lat =  -34.4166942, zoom = 12)
  })
}
```